# Fill in the missing countries

Tags: knowledge, geography

In the square table below, fill in the missing countries. (The slightly different background color of the first row is not important; it's an artifact of how tables are implemented in Markdown)

| Afghanistan | Bosnia and Herzegovina | France |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Haiti** | ? | **Dominican Republic** |
| **Central African Republic** | ? | **Guadeloupe** |

Please explain your answer.

**Hint 1**

> There are two major patterns here

**Hint 2**

> It is a Magic Square of ----

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is mostly given in various comments so I will simply confirm it as follows:

> The puzzle is a 3x3 Magic Square of  numbers 1 to 9 ( adding to 15).The numbers come from the vowels in the name of the country. 
>  
>  Each country has number of vowels with 5 (center) and 1 missing. The countries are alphabetical. So the answer is countries starting with E and I with 1 and 5 vowels
>  
>  They are Indonesia in the center and Egypt in the bottom row.

Answer (score 9):

I think the missing countries are

> **Equatorial Guinea** and **Ivory Coast**

The following observations led me to that conclusion:

> * The country names seem to be following an alphabetic progression.  If we add a country that starts with **E** and one that starts with **I**, we will have the first nine letters of the alphabet.
>
>  * If $n$ is the number of words in the country's name, there are $5-n$ countries with that many words in the grid.  So for $1$-word names, there are $4$ countries, for $2$-word names, there are $3$ countries, and for $3$-word names, there are $2$ countries.
>
>  * **Conclusion:** Both missing countries need to have $2$-word names, and one needs to start with **E** and the other with **I**.  The countries listed above are the only ones that meet those criteria.

Comment: Wow. Very creative, But there is another hidden Major pattern @GentlePurpleRain

Comment: which one goes in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

Partial... Looks like we need countries that

> start with I and E

and

> have 5 and 6 syllables

one could be

> Ethiopia

but don't know what the second one can be....

Comment: That's a good answer. rot13(Vaqbarfvn pbhyq or nabgure svir-flyynoyr pbhagel. V thrff gur ynfg pbhagel vfa'g ernyyl na vaqrcraqrag pbhagel va vgf bja evtug. Nsgre nyy, Thnqrybhcr vf nyernql va gur tevq, jurer cebcre pbhagevrf pbhyq unir svg gur ovyy.)

Comment: Yes, rot13(Fvzvyneyl vg znl or ibjry pbhagf).

Comment: @Tom: Ah, that's a good obesrvation! rot13(Fb vg'f Vaqbarfvn naq Rtlcg, nygubhtu gur L vf n ibjry gurer.)

Comment: @MOehm - needs a dream team GPR/jafe/M Oehm (and me:P) to meet a DEEM -  looks good to include

Comment: "Square" @jaffe  means something. You guys are correct about E and I but location and countries??

Comment: From the hint, rot13(gur ibjry pbhagf sbez n zntvp fdhner).  More to this than I thought - nicely arranged Deem!

Comment: @Tom. Thanks. Question. Most comments here are unreadable to me because they incorporate spoilers? How do I read them?

Comment: @DEEM rot13.com :)

Comment: Wow   You guys have it. Why not answer?